# The submit button works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I developed a function that keeps the submit disabled until filling all the fields. The function works, but when I create two more users the submit button enables before filling the fields; my function works only once.

The button is working and the data is saved, but the submit button is enabled before filling the fields.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myForm input').keyup(function () {
            var empty = false;
            $('#myForm input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $('#btnsave').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#btnsave').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            return empty;
        });
    });
```

Comment: By "when I create two more user", does it mean you are dynamically adding new `<input>` elements to the form? To bind event listeners to dynamically added elements that are not present at runtime, you will have to use `.on()`

Comment: I'm guessing the button is created dynamically.

Comment: How uses .on() ?

Comment: Check here how to delegate events using .on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: almost I find the solution, but the problem is when creates second user, the button submit disable if we click on one of the fields

Answer (score 0):

i think you create new inputs dynamically, then try this:

```
$('#myForm').on('keyup', 'input', function () {
            var empty = false;
        $('#myForm input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#btnsave').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnsave').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        return empty;
    });
});
```

Comment: almost I find the solution, but the problem is when creates second user, the button submit disable if we click on one of the fields